# Create the .gcloudignore file by a command line

Tags: gcloud

Is there a gcloud command line to create the gcloudignore file ? I checked a little bit in their documenation and I didn't find my answer

Comment: You would create that file yourself: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore Also Google search for a similar file: .gitignore.

Comment: yes, i just wanted to know if there is a default command in the gcloud CLI